# C# - Any Code optimization technique for Overriding "Equals"?

Tags: c#

Normally ( Based on my understanding ) i have to follow a lot of steps to

override the "Equals" to check the state of the object.

Example :

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
       if (obj is SalesPerson && obj != null)
       {

         SalesPerson temp;

         temp = (SalesPerson)obj;

           if (temp.fName == this.fName && temp.lName == this.fName 
              && temp.personAge == this.personAge )
              {

                 return true;
              }

          else
          {
            return false;
          }

      }
       return false;
     }
```

---

Any other alternative like LINQ or other techniques gives me shortcut code ?

**Update :**

Moreover i gusess i have to override GetHasCode() too when i override "Equals".

Comment: Class or struct? And yes, you'll need GetHashCode() too.

Comment: Yep - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx.aspx

Comment: There's an IEquatable<T>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the answers so far seem mostly fine to me. However, you should carefully consider what you want equality to mean in an inheritance hierarchy. Can an instance of just `SalesPerson` be equal to an instance of `SalesManager` (which would derive from `SalesPerson`)?

The trouble is, the symmetric nature of equals gets in the way. Suppose we have:

```
SalesPerson x = new SalesPerson { ... };
SalesManager y = new SalesManager { ... };
```

I'd expect `y.Equals(x)` to be false - which means that `x.Equals(y)` ought to be false too.

This means the check in `SalesPerson` *really* needs to be:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    SalesPerson salesPerson = obj as SalePerson;
    if (salesPerson == null) return false;
    return salesPerson.GetType() == this.GetType() &&
           salesPerson.fName == this.fName && 
           salesPerson.lName == this.fName && 
           salesPerson.personAge == this.personAge;
}
```

Note that I'm *not* comparing with `typeof(SalesPerson)` as the implementation in `SalesManager` would probably want to call up to this implementation first.

Of course, all of this complication goes away if `SalesPerson` is sealed... another reason for being very careful before introducing inheritance :)

Comment: would it possible to use  IEquatable<T> ?

Comment: @jrista: The property that x = y implies y = x is known as symmetry, not commutativity.

Answer (score 7):

This looks neater:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  SalesPerson salesPerson = obj as SalePerson;
  if(salesPerson == null) return false;
  return salesPerson.fName == this.fName && 
         salesPerson.lName == this.fName && 
         salesPerson.personAge == this.personAge;
}
```

Comment: Doh! Typed it in faster that me :-)

Comment: :) almost same answers from two person :)

Answer (score 6):

And of course if you **really** wanted to compact it into a single line you could use:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  SalesPerson salesPerson = obj as SalePerson;

  return (salesPerson != null) &&
         (salesPerson.fName == this.fName && 
         salesPerson.lName == this.fName && 
         salesPerson.personAge == this.personAge);
}
```

The test for non-null is guaranteed to run first and therefore no potential NullReferenceException can occur in the rest of the equality test.

Answer (score 2):

You code seems very overcomplicated. I'd replace it with this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {

    SalesPerson temp = obj as SalesPerson;
        if(temp == null) return false;

    return temp.fName == this.fName && temp.lName == this.fName 
              && temp.personAge == this.personAge;
     }
```

You could then write some operators == != etc..

Comment: salute to both Preet and Charlie :)

Comment: In your example, obj == null should be temp == null. In the event that obj is not a SalesPerson but also not null, checking obj == null rather than temp == null would result in a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the **reflector tool** and learn best practices directly from Microsoft's code.

For example, `System.Reflection.Module` class equals function implementation:

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
    if (o == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(o is Module))
    {
        return false;
    }
    Module internalModule = o as Module;
    internalModule = internalModule.InternalModule;
    return (this.InternalModule == internalModule);
}
```

EDIT: Changed the implementation example to `Module` class.

Comment: Thank you very much Eran Betzalel

Comment: Please note that DateTime is a struct, and thus they do not have to do null checks.

Comment: And that this is the `IEqualityComparer<DateTime>.Equals` implementation, not the override of `object.Equals` - so there's no need to do type checking.

Comment: You're missing the point my friends. The main idea of the answer was to use reflector. `DateTime` was just an example, you can find a lot of these in the reflector.

Answer (score 1):

I find Resharper a very useful tool for 'drudge' work such as this, and can certainly help you focus on what you are trying to achieve over the implementation detail.

See [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/AdvEditing/generateEquals.html)  for more info. If there are alternatives I'm open to hear them.